# Delphi : WSDL Import can't Handle Object

Tags: delphi, wsdl, delphi-xe

There is a third party web service application on bellow address
http://webservice.magfa.com/services/urn:SOAPSmsQueue?wsdl
I want to use method "getAllMessages" which returns array of object named "CustomerReturnIncomingFormat", but delphi wsdl importer failed to import properly.
And generated  as "ArrayOf_xsd_anyType : array of variant" !!!
It seems that delphi can't import objects from wsdl !?
any idea?

Comment: which Delphi version? And what's the error message?

Comment: I can replicate the behavior. What happens when you execute the method?

Comment: I used Delphi XE when I call method I get array of empty strings

Comment: I had a look at the WSDL and I don't see anything wrong with the generated unit, in fact ArrayOf_xsd_anyType can be ArrayOf_xsd_int ArrayOf_xsd_string or ArrayOf_xsd_long. So array of variant would be the correct match on the delphi side. Fire up wireshark and add the XML content you get after the GetAllMessages call. I tried to reprocude but I get 401 unauthorized, so I can't test this.

Comment: Or use Fiddler to catch the HTTP traffic

Comment: Dear whosrdaddy, thanks for your test. In service document and .net samples about "getAllMessages" says that it returns array of object "CustomerReturnIncomingFormat".In wsdl file I notice the given (return) object is presented but function's return is "ArrayOf_xsd_anyType". so delphi can't link return of function to object. In .Net sample, returned value casted with CustomerReturnIncomingFormat[]. How force delphi to create object's equivalant wrapper? Thanks for all who help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that the programmer has been lazy and made one ArrayOf_xsd_anyType declaration for all calls that return in fact an array of objects. The WSDL importer tries to map this type as good as it can to an array of variant. Since you have the documentation you know exactly what each service calls returns. The easiest way is to fix the WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<definitions targetNamespace="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:impl="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" xmlns:intf="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns1="urn:SOAPSmsQueue" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <wsdl:types>
    <schema targetNamespace="urn:SOAPSmsQueue" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      <complexType name="CustomerReturnIncomingFormat">
        <sequence>
          <element name="body" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
          <element name="errorResult" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
          <element name="recipientNumber" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
          <element name="senderNumber" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
        </sequence>
      </complexType>
      <complexType name="DatedCustomerReturnIncomingFormat">
        <complexContent>
          <extension base="tns1:CustomerReturnIncomingFormat">
            <sequence>
              <element name="date" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
            </sequence>
          </extension>
        </complexContent>
      </complexType>
    </schema>
    <schema targetNamespace="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      <complexType name="ArrayOf_xsd_string">
        <complexContent>
          <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
            <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:string[]" />
          </restriction>
        </complexContent>
      </complexType>
      <complexType name="ArrayOf_xsd_int">
        <complexContent>
          <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
            <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:int[]" />
          </restriction>
        </complexContent>
      </complexType>
      <complexType name="ArrayOf_xsd_long">
        <complexContent>
          <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
            <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:long[]" />
          </restriction>
        </complexContent>
      </complexType>
      <complexType name="ArrayOf_xsd_anyType">
        <complexContent>
          <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
            <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:anyType[]" />
          </restriction>
        </complexContent>
      </complexType>
      <complexType name="ArrayOf_CustomerReturnIncomingFormat">
        <complexContent>
          <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
            <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:CustomerReturnIncomingFormat[]" />
          </restriction>
        </complexContent>
      </complexType>
    </schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <message name="getAllMessagesRequest">
    <part name="domain" type="xsd:string" />
    <part name="numberOfMessages" type="xsd:int" />
  </message>
  <message name="getCreditResponse">
    <part name="getCreditReturn" type="xsd:float" />
  </message>
  <message name="getMessageIdRequest">
    <part name="domain" type="xsd:string" />
    <part name="checkingMessageId" type="xsd:long" />
  </message>
  <message name="getMessagesWithNumberResponse">
    <part name="getMessagesWithNumberReturn" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_anyType" />
  </message>
  <message name="getMessageStatusesRequest">
    <part name="messagesId" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_long" />
  </message>
  <message name="getRealMessageStatusesRequest">
    <part name="messagesId" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_long" />
  </message>
  <message name="enqueueWithGatewayRequest">
    <part name="domain" type="xsd:string" />
    <part name="messageBodies" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_string" />
    <part name="recipientNumbers" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_string" />
    <part name="senderNumbers" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_string" />
    <part name="encodings" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_int" />
    <part name="udhs" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_string" />
    <part name="messageClasses" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_int" />
    <part name="priorities" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_int" />
    <part name="checkingMessageIds" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_long" />
    <part name="gateway" type="xsd:string" />
  </message>
  <message name="getAllMessagesResponse">
    <part name="getAllMessagesReturn" type="impl:ArrayOf_CustomerReturnIncomingFormat" />
  </message>
  <message name="getAllMessagesWithNumberResponse">
    <part name="getAllMessagesWithNumberReturn" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_anyType" />
  </message>
  <message name="enqueueResponse">
    <part name="enqueueReturn" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_long" />
  </message>
  <message name="getMessageStatusesResponse">
    <part name="getMessageStatusesReturn" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_int" />
  </message>
  <message name="getMessageStatusRequest">
    <part name="messageId" type="xsd:long" />
  </message>
  <message name="getMessagesResponse">
    <part name="getMessagesReturn" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_anyType" />
  </message>
  <message name="getMessagesRequest">
    <part name="domain" type="xsd:string" />
    <part name="numberOfMessages" type="xsd:int" />
  </message>
  <message name="getAllMessagesWithNumberRequest">
    <part name="domain" type="xsd:string" />
    <part name="numberOfMessages" type="xsd:int" />
    <part name="destNumber" type="xsd:string" />
  </message>
  <message name="enqueueRequest">
    <part name="domain" type="xsd:string" />
    <part name="messageBodies" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_string" />
    <part name="recipientNumbers" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_string" />
    <part name="senderNumbers" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_string" />
    <part name="encodings" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_int" />
    <part name="udhs" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_string" />
    <part name="messageClasses" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_int" />
    <part name="priorities" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_int" />
    <part name="checkingMessageIds" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_long" />
  </message>
  <message name="getRealMessageStatusesResponse">
    <part name="getRealMessageStatusesReturn" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_int" />
  </message>
  <message name="getMessagesWithNumberRequest">
    <part name="domain" type="xsd:string" />
    <part name="numberOfMessages" type="xsd:int" />
    <part name="destNumber" type="xsd:string" />
  </message>
  <message name="getMessageIdResponse">
    <part name="getMessageIdReturn" type="xsd:long" />
  </message>
  <message name="getCreditRequest">
    <part name="domain" type="xsd:string" />
  </message>
  <message name="getMessageStatusResponse">
    <part name="getMessageStatusReturn" type="xsd:int" />
  </message>
  <message name="enqueueWithGatewayResponse">
    <part name="enqueueWithGatewayReturn" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_long" />
  </message>
  <portType name="SoapSmsQueuableImplementation">
    <operation name="enqueue" parameterOrder="domain messageBodies recipientNumbers senderNumbers encodings udhs messageClasses priorities checkingMessageIds">
      <input message="impl:enqueueRequest" name="enqueueRequest" />
      <output message="impl:enqueueResponse" name="enqueueResponse" />
    </operation>
    <operation name="getMessages" parameterOrder="domain numberOfMessages">
      <input message="impl:getMessagesRequest" name="getMessagesRequest" />
      <output message="impl:getMessagesResponse" name="getMessagesResponse" />
    </operation>
    <operation name="getMessageId" parameterOrder="domain checkingMessageId">
      <input message="impl:getMessageIdRequest" name="getMessageIdRequest" />
      <output message="impl:getMessageIdResponse" name="getMessageIdResponse" />
    </operation>
    <operation name="getRealMessageStatuses" parameterOrder="messagesId">
      <input message="impl:getRealMessageStatusesRequest" name="getRealMessageStatusesRequest" />
      <output message="impl:getRealMessageStatusesResponse" name="getRealMessageStatusesResponse" />
    </operation>
    <operation name="getAllMessagesWithNumber" parameterOrder="domain numberOfMessages destNumber">
      <input message="impl:getAllMessagesWithNumberRequest" name="getAllMessagesWithNumberRequest" />
      <output message="impl:getAllMessagesWithNumberResponse" name="getAllMessagesWithNumberResponse" />
    </operation>
    <operation name="getMessagesWithNumber" parameterOrder="domain numberOfMessages destNumber">
      <input message="impl:getMessagesWithNumberRequest" name="getMessagesWithNumberRequest" />
      <output message="impl:getMessagesWithNumberResponse" name="getMessagesWithNumberResponse" />
    </operation>
    <operation name="getCredit" parameterOrder="domain">
      <input message="impl:getCreditRequest" name="getCreditRequest" />
      <output message="impl:getCreditResponse" name="getCreditResponse" />
    </operation>
    <operation name="getAllMessages" parameterOrder="domain numberOfMessages">
      <input message="impl:getAllMessagesRequest" name="getAllMessagesRequest" />
      <output message="impl:getAllMessagesResponse" name="getAllMessagesResponse" />
    </operation>
    <operation name="enqueueWithGateway" parameterOrder="domain messageBodies recipientNumbers senderNumbers encodings udhs messageClasses priorities checkingMessageIds gateway">
      <input message="impl:enqueueWithGatewayRequest" name="enqueueWithGatewayRequest" />
      <output message="impl:enqueueWithGatewayResponse" name="enqueueWithGatewayResponse" />
    </operation>
    <operation name="getMessageStatuses" parameterOrder="messagesId">
      <input message="impl:getMessageStatusesRequest" name="getMessageStatusesRequest" />
      <output message="impl:getMessageStatusesResponse" name="getMessageStatusesResponse" />
    </operation>
    <operation name="getMessageStatus" parameterOrder="messageId">
      <input message="impl:getMessageStatusRequest" name="getMessageStatusRequest" />
      <output message="impl:getMessageStatusResponse" name="getMessageStatusResponse" />
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="TSOAPSoapBinding" type="impl:SoapSmsQueuableImplementation">
    <wsdlsoap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <operation name="enqueue">
      <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="" />
      <input name="enqueueRequest">
        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" use="encoded" />
      </input>
      <output name="enqueueResponse">
        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" use="encoded" />
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getMessages">
      <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="" />
      <input name="getMessagesRequest">
        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" use="encoded" />
      </input>
      <output name="getMessagesResponse">
        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" use="encoded" />
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getMessageId">
      <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="" />
      <input name="getMessageIdRequest">
        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" use="encoded" />
      </input>
      <output name="getMessageIdResponse">
        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" use="encoded" />
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getRealMessageStatuses">
      <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="" />
      <input name="getRealMessageStatusesRequest">
        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" use="encoded" />
      </input>
      <output name="getRealMessageStatusesResponse">
        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" use="encoded" />
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getAllMessagesWithNumber">
      <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="" />
      <input name="getAllMessagesWithNumberRequest">
        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" use="encoded" />
      </input>
      <output name="getAllMessagesWithNumberResponse">
        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" use="encoded" />
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getMessagesWithNumber">
      <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="" />
      <input name="getMessagesWithNumberRequest">
        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" use="encoded" />
      </input>
      <output name="getMessagesWithNumberResponse">
        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" use="encoded" />
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getCredit">
      <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="" />
      <input name="getCreditRequest">
        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" use="encoded" />
      </input>
      <output name="getCreditResponse">
        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" use="encoded" />
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getAllMessages">
      <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="" />
      <input name="getAllMessagesRequest">
        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" use="encoded" />
      </input>
      <output name="getAllMessagesResponse">
        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" use="encoded" />
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="enqueueWithGateway">
      <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="" />
      <input name="enqueueWithGatewayRequest">
        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" use="encoded" />
      </input>
      <output name="enqueueWithGatewayResponse">
        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" use="encoded" />
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getMessageStatuses">
      <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="" />
      <input name="getMessageStatusesRequest">
        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" use="encoded" />
      </input>
      <output name="getMessageStatusesResponse">
        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" use="encoded" />
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getMessageStatus">
      <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="" />
      <input name="getMessageStatusRequest">
        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" use="encoded" />
      </input>
      <output name="getMessageStatusResponse">
        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" use="encoded" />
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="SoapSmsQueuableImplementationService">
    <port binding="impl:TSOAPSoapBinding" name="TSOAP">
      <wsdlsoap:address location="http://webservice.magfa.com/services/urn:SOAPSmsQueue" />
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

I just added a definition for ArrayOf_CustomerReturnIncomingFormat and changed the return value type from the getAllMessagesReturn part to this definition.

Make sure that when you import this wsdl file that you turn off the "Do not emit unused types (-Ot)" option. This is the resulting unit when importing the fixed WSDL file with delphi XE:

```
unit SOAPSmsQueue;

interface

uses InvokeRegistry, SOAPHTTPClient, Types, XSBuiltIns;

type

  // ************************************************************************ //
  // The following types, referred to in the WSDL document are not being represented
  // in this file. They are either aliases[@] of other types represented or were referred
  // to but never[!] declared in the document. The types from the latter category
  // typically map to predefined/known XML or Embarcadero types; however, they could also
  // indicate incorrect WSDL documents that failed to declare or import a schema type.
  // ************************************************************************ //
  // !:anyType         - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[Gbl]
  // !:float           - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[]
  // !:CustomerReturnIncomingFormat - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[Gbl]
  // !:long            - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[Gbl]
  // !:string          - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[Gbl]
  // !:int             - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[Gbl]

  CustomerReturnIncomingFormat = class;         { "urn:SOAPSmsQueue"[!U][GblCplx] }
  DatedCustomerReturnIncomingFormat = class;    { "urn:SOAPSmsQueue"[!U][GblCplx] }

  ArrayOf_xsd_anyType = array of Variant;       { "http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue"[GblCplx] }
  ArrayOf_CustomerReturnIncomingFormat = array of CustomerReturnIncomingFormat;   { "http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue"[GblCplx] }
  ArrayOf_xsd_string = array of string;         { "http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue"[GblCplx] }


  // ************************************************************************ //
  // XML       : CustomerReturnIncomingFormat, global, <complexType>
  // Namespace : urn:SOAPSmsQueue
  // ************************************************************************ //
  CustomerReturnIncomingFormat = class(TRemotable)
  private
    Fbody: string;
    FerrorResult: string;
    FrecipientNumber: string;
    FsenderNumber: string;
  published
    property body:            string  read Fbody write Fbody;
    property errorResult:     string  read FerrorResult write FerrorResult;
    property recipientNumber: string  read FrecipientNumber write FrecipientNumber;
    property senderNumber:    string  read FsenderNumber write FsenderNumber;
  end;



  // ************************************************************************ //
  // XML       : DatedCustomerReturnIncomingFormat, global, <complexType>
  // Namespace : urn:SOAPSmsQueue
  // ************************************************************************ //
  DatedCustomerReturnIncomingFormat = class(CustomerReturnIncomingFormat)
  private
    Fdate: string;
  published
    property date: string  read Fdate write Fdate;
  end;

  ArrayOf_xsd_long = array of Int64;            { "http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue"[GblCplx] }
  ArrayOf_xsd_int = array of Integer;           { "http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue"[GblCplx] }

  // ************************************************************************ //
  // Namespace : http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue
  // transport : http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http
  // style     : rpc
  // use       : encoded
  // binding   : TSOAPSoapBinding
  // service   : SoapSmsQueuableImplementationService
  // port      : TSOAP
  // URL       : http://webservice.magfa.com/services/urn:SOAPSmsQueue
  // ************************************************************************ //
  SoapSmsQueuableImplementation = interface(IInvokable)
  ['{9DBBFB75-511D-1D3D-5200-4133705D96F5}']
    function  enqueue(const domain: string; const messageBodies: ArrayOf_xsd_string; const recipientNumbers: ArrayOf_xsd_string; const senderNumbers: ArrayOf_xsd_string; const encodings: ArrayOf_xsd_int; const udhs: ArrayOf_xsd_string;
                      const messageClasses: ArrayOf_xsd_int; const priorities: ArrayOf_xsd_int; const checkingMessageIds: ArrayOf_xsd_long): ArrayOf_xsd_long; stdcall;
    function  getMessages(const domain: string; const numberOfMessages: Integer): ArrayOf_xsd_anyType; stdcall;
    function  getMessageId(const domain: string; const checkingMessageId: Int64): Int64; stdcall;
    function  getRealMessageStatuses(const messagesId: ArrayOf_xsd_long): ArrayOf_xsd_int; stdcall;
    function  getAllMessagesWithNumber(const domain: string; const numberOfMessages: Integer; const destNumber: string): ArrayOf_xsd_anyType; stdcall;
    function  getMessagesWithNumber(const domain: string; const numberOfMessages: Integer; const destNumber: string): ArrayOf_xsd_anyType; stdcall;
    function  getCredit(const domain: string): Single; stdcall;
    function  getAllMessages(const domain: string; const numberOfMessages: Integer): ArrayOf_CustomerReturnIncomingFormat; stdcall;
    function  enqueueWithGateway(const domain: string; const messageBodies: ArrayOf_xsd_string; const recipientNumbers: ArrayOf_xsd_string; const senderNumbers: ArrayOf_xsd_string; const encodings: ArrayOf_xsd_int; const udhs: ArrayOf_xsd_string;
                                 const messageClasses: ArrayOf_xsd_int; const priorities: ArrayOf_xsd_int; const checkingMessageIds: ArrayOf_xsd_long; const gateway: string): ArrayOf_xsd_long; stdcall;
    function  getMessageStatuses(const messagesId: ArrayOf_xsd_long): ArrayOf_xsd_int; stdcall;
    function  getMessageStatus(const messageId: Int64): Integer; stdcall;
  end;

function GetSoapSmsQueuableImplementation(UseWSDL: Boolean=System.False; Addr: string=''; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO = nil): SoapSmsQueuableImplementation;


implementation
  uses SysUtils;

function GetSoapSmsQueuableImplementation(UseWSDL: Boolean; Addr: string; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO): SoapSmsQueuableImplementation;
const
  defWSDL = 'C:\Temp\SOAPSmsQueue.xml';
  defURL  = 'http://webservice.magfa.com/services/urn:SOAPSmsQueue';
  defSvc  = 'SoapSmsQueuableImplementationService';
  defPrt  = 'TSOAP';
var
  RIO: THTTPRIO;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if (Addr = '') then
  begin
    if UseWSDL then
      Addr := defWSDL
    else
      Addr := defURL;
  end;
  if HTTPRIO = nil then
    RIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil)
  else
    RIO := HTTPRIO;
  try
    Result := (RIO as SoapSmsQueuableImplementation);
    if UseWSDL then
    begin
      RIO.WSDLLocation := Addr;
      RIO.Service := defSvc;
      RIO.Port := defPrt;
    end else
      RIO.URL := Addr;
  finally
    if (Result = nil) and (HTTPRIO = nil) then
      RIO.Free;
  end;
end;


initialization
  { SoapSmsQueuableImplementation }
  InvRegistry.RegisterInterface(TypeInfo(SoapSmsQueuableImplementation), 'http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue', 'utf-8');
  InvRegistry.RegisterDefaultSOAPAction(TypeInfo(SoapSmsQueuableImplementation), '');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSInfo(TypeInfo(ArrayOf_xsd_anyType), 'http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue', 'ArrayOf_xsd_anyType');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSInfo(TypeInfo(ArrayOf_CustomerReturnIncomingFormat), 'http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue', 'ArrayOf_CustomerReturnIncomingFormat');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSInfo(TypeInfo(ArrayOf_xsd_string), 'http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue', 'ArrayOf_xsd_string');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(CustomerReturnIncomingFormat, 'urn:SOAPSmsQueue', 'CustomerReturnIncomingFormat');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(DatedCustomerReturnIncomingFormat, 'urn:SOAPSmsQueue', 'DatedCustomerReturnIncomingFormat');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSInfo(TypeInfo(ArrayOf_xsd_long), 'http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue', 'ArrayOf_xsd_long');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSInfo(TypeInfo(ArrayOf_xsd_int), 'http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue', 'ArrayOf_xsd_int');

end.
```

Comment: Dear whosrdaddy, Many Thanks for your tests and answer. Unfortunately web server configuration is not accessible and I can't correct response type from origin (webservice). As you said I turned off "Do not emit unused types (-Ot)" option and now I have CustomerReturnIncomingFormat type in my wrapper. I tried to use it as CustomerReturnIncomingFormat(res[0]); but compiler gets invalid typecast error ! what can I do to cast it and reach to return value as object? thanks for nice advise

Comment: You don't have to do that, just fix the wsdl like I did in the code example above and Delphi will generate the correct code...

Comment: Dear whosrdaddy, Many Thanks again for your advise. I done and get answer. wow great trick!!. Thanking you again and be happy